# Magento2 get url of all CMS pages using their identifiers

Tags: url, magento-2.2.5, cms-pages

I am preparing one common array which returns the complete details of all CMS pages. In this array, I need to pass the URL of all cms pages. I do have an identifier of all pages. How can I get the URL from it? Does anyone have an idea? Though it looks simple but bit tricky.

I have already used `getPageUrl()` function extending `\Magento\Cms\Helper\Page` helper class. But it simply adds the page identifier behind the store URL. Like for homepage, it returns http://127.0.0.1/magento2/home same as for 404 page it returns http://127.0.0.1/magento2/no-route.

Here is the code snippet I have used:

```
<?php

namespace Sample\Core\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
   /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page
     */
    protected $cmsHelper;

    public function __construct(       
        \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $cmsHelper       
    ) {        
        $this->cmsHelper = $cmsHelper;       
    }

    public function getSeoData($cmsData)
    {
        $url = $this->cmsHelper->getPageUrl($cmsData->getPageId());
    }
}
```

Here is the screen-shot of backend configuration,

[image]

Is there any intelligent function available in Magento2 which automatically understand this return the correct URL of all cms pages?

Any help into this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please upload your code and cms page grid screenshots?

Comment: @RohanHapani, Thanks for quick response. I have added code and screen-shot as you mentioned. Please see my updated question. Let me know if you have any query.